# HttpClient instance is undefined in Angular 6 service

Tags: angular

I have a service that wraps `HttpClient`. That service is called by a component. The problem is that when I inject the service in the component constructor it is `undefined`. Moreover, the service constructor seems to not execute at all as a `console.log` does not print anything. Any ideas?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyHttpService {

  constructor(public httpx: HttpClient) {
        console.log("in the constructor - " + this.httpx) // <-- this is never printed
  }

  call () {
        let reqData = { act: 'R'};
        this.httpx.post('/myurl', reqData).subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
          }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
    }
}
```

The related module is defined as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyHttpService } from './http.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    HttpClient
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyHttpService
  ],
  exports: [
    MyHttpService
  ]
})
export class CoreServiceModule {}
```

The component that calls the service:

```
@Component({
      selector: 'some-selector',
      templateUrl: 'some-url.html'
    })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{ 

    constructor(public http:MyHttpService){
          console.log(http);  // <-- this prints undefined
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let x = this.http.call();  // <-- this fails as http is undefined       
    }


}
```

And the component module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  exports: [MyComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, CoreServiceModule],
  bootstrap: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be in the providers array ?

Comment: Your class CoreServiceModule should contain a `forRoot()` method that returns an object with at least `ngModule` and `providers` property.

Comment: You need not add the service to "exports" & "declaration" arrays, instead, you should add it into the "providers" array.

Comment: seems like you don't have a basic knowledge of services.

Comment: I'm just starting with Angular 6, spent long hours trying to make this work and putting together the question. Also. nobody could give me the answer, so apparently is not that basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I'm new to Angular, but I've done something similar recently and looking at my own similar project, I've spotted a few differences:

**1.** When injecting the httpClient, it's a private rather than public

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

**2.** I think you need to include

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

at the top of your MyHttpService module.

**3.** Note that you've got the same module define twice under a different name:

```
HttpClientModule, 
HttpClient
```

I'd remove one to tidiness sake.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE - 1:**

This is what I have in my test app. Hopefully, you'll spot something different but it definitely works for me.

**app.module.ts:**

```
…
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
…
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  …
],
imports: [
    …
    HttpClientModule,
    …
  ],
}],
providers: [HttpService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I create a separate file for my http client service.

**http.service.ts:**

```
…
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
…

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HttpService {

  private _loginUrl = "http://...";

  …

  // inject http client in constructor. Make sure it is imported.

  constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

  // Sample function
  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._loginUrl, user);
  }
}
```

and from my view/component:

**login.component.ts:**

```
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  …
  constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  loginUser() {
      this._http.loginUser(this.loginUserData).subscribe...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't post all the imports, I'm already importing HttpClient. I tried with private and public, and get the same error. I also trying importing only the HttpClientModule, but still didn't help.

Comment: I've added more details in my answer based on my solution. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Note that I've had to edit my additional details a couple of times as I had missed something. One important part I had omitted was the providers. I added it but I've removed details that were required to deal with JWT so I'm not 100% sure whether or not this is how you define a single provider.

Comment: The only difference I could see with my code is that you have providers: [MyHttpService], I tried that and didn't work either, sorry :(

Comment: found the problem, an export was missing http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdF42h6hRc4f6ZX3ZDiq?p=preview

Comment: Great! But where was the import missing from?

Comment: I meant 'export' btw but can you specify where was it missing from? which file/class/etc... Thank

Comment: My bad, I meant import, BankModule in App module

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that, do not forget to importe `ModuleWithProviders` interface from `@angular/core`.

```
export class CoreServiceModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreServiceModule,
      providers: [MyHttpService]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to import this "shared module" in your app.module.ts, and when you declare it in the app.module, you must call forRoot() method.
You are then able to use this singleton anywhere in your application without any risk to be re-instanciated.

Comment: Is this native Angular 6? I thought that `@NgModule` is used only as a decoration

Comment: I still get the http `undefined`, sorry :(

Comment: In your ngModule, do you have  `imports: CoreServiceModule.forRoot()` ?

Comment: Maybe you could share code with floobits or something ? Angular DI fails to instanciate the service, but I don't see why

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue:

```
this.httpx is undefined
```

For my greatest surprise, changing the function in the service to arrow function solved the problem:

```
  call = () => {
        let reqData = { act: 'R'};
        this.httpx.post('/myurl', reqData).subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
          }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));
    }
```

Anytime something of `this` is undefined, first thing I check is if "arrowing" the function helps. More times than what I'm comfortable with, it does. I must assume that this is the doing of the good-old javascript this-fiasco.